# Activity Dialogs through AppCompat-v7 for material designs don't have titles

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm migrating my app to AppCompat-v7 and have hit a road-block.

I have 3 Activity dialogs, specifically they were Holo.Light.Dialog types. When I gave them the parent theme: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`, they suddenly had no titles.

How would I get the titles back? By title, I mean what one used to see in non-material design AlertDialogs with the Large text and horizontal blue line under it.